# How to add listeners to components that are defined within itemTpl?

Tags: html, extjs, dataview

How to add listeners to components that are defined within itemTpl? For example, if I have a dataview (Ext.view.View) that is bound to a store, and I have defined itempTpl that includes a button and an image, like:

```
itemTpl: ['<div class="card" style="padding-left: 32px;">',
'<div><button type="button" class="btn"><span>Button</span></button></div>',
'<div class="img"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"></div>',                
'</div>']
```

how can I detect that button or image of an item is clicked? I know ho to add listeners to the item, but I would like to detect click event on some inner div or span element of an item.

In addition, I found writing these templates with html very difficult. One of the main advantages of extjs framework is claimed to be exactly hiding html part from the developer. So, I am wondering if there is some better way to display these information with dataview, like including panel or container component as an dataview item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use element delegation:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('Image', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'src',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'caption',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            id: 'imagesStore',
            model: 'Image',
            data: [{
                src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-drawing.png',
                caption: 'Drawing & Charts'
            }, {
                src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-data.png',
                caption: 'Advanced Data'
            }, {
                src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png',
                caption: 'Overhauled Theme'
            }, {
                src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-perf.png',
                caption: 'Performance Tuned'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<div class="card" style="padding-left: 32px;">',
                '<div><button type="button" class="btn"><span class="btnSpan">Button</span></button></div>',
                '<div class="img"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" class="imgClass"></div>',
                '</div>',
            ),
            itemSelector: 'div.card',
            emptyText: 'No images available',
            listeners: {
                itemClick: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                    console.log(e.target);
                    const classList = e.target.classList;
                    if (classList.contains('btn')) {
                        console.log('btn is clicked');
                    } else if (classList.contains('btnSpan')) {
                        console.log('Span in Button is clicked');
                    } else if (classList.contains('imgClass')) {
                        console.log('ImgClass is clicked');
                    }
                }
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arhtur. Could you please complete your answer with click on button? I tried to replace div.img with div.btn, but it doesn't work. In addition, what if there is another element (for example <div class="img1"...)? How can I delegate each element separately?

Comment: I have updated the answer for button. There is a path in the delegate..

Comment: Thanks, but now you erased the click on image :). I would like to have both, and to distinguish whether it was clicked on image or on button.

Comment: Updated last time :D